# Is there a way to find/detect the middle of two pixels, or two lines created by opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, image-recognition

I am trying to create a lane detection system, I need to find the middle of the two lines drawn by opencv as shown below:
[Two Lines created by fillPoly() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xagxE.jpg)

I need to find the middle of these two lines (or one of the two pixels from the lines) to create a dot or another line in the middle of these so I could detect the car changing lane.
Thank You.

Comment: `(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2`

Comment: when I use this I get this error:     cv2.line(blankImage, (x1 + x2)/2 , (y1 + y2)/2, (255, 0, 0), thickness=50)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have two parallel lines L1 (x1, y1) - (x2, y2) and L2 (x3, y3) - (x4, y4), the middle line is a simple mean from these two values like Zabir said to you in comments.

But pay attention to the line method for drawing, as show in the docs below:

```
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
cv.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
```

Here the line is from point (0, 0) to (511, 511) which is passed as a tuple format hence the error message you got

> SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

So for fixing this you just need to provide in the right way, something like:

```
cv.line(img,(x1_middle, y1_middle),(x2_middle,y2_middle),(255,0,0),5)
```

[Take a look here for drawing functions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html)

- Edit based on comment

Since I supposed it was two parallel lines and not an intersection, the problem again it's just math calculus. If you have two lines L1: y = 2x and L2: y = 20 - 2x the intersection between these two lines is the point were both have the same x and y, so for finding that just resolve for the simple system:

2x - y = 0

2x + y = 20

Which results in x = 5, y = 10 (base for the green line).

[image: Plot intersection]

Comment: I wrote this (https://imgur.com/Ersi9es) according to your instructions but I ended up with these (https://imgur.com/mhX0Hyi and https://imgur.com/8R63yFj) instead of something like this (https://imgur.com/JisGw3T) which I want it to be constant so I can detect the car's movement between the lanes.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer but unluckily I don't understand one more part, which is: Yes x1_Middle = (x1+x2)/2 and y1_middle = (y1+y2)/2 but what are x2_middle and y2_middle? @Gabriel Domene

Comment: @RalfiBahar I think we made an mistake... (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are points which if connected make a line right? The middle POINT is the mean of each axis (x1+x2)/2, so for a middle line between you need TWO more points (another line) like (x3, y3) and (x4, y4). I've update the answer again clarifying this first point, but I think the problem here is more geometry in your part than the opencv itself.

Comment: Glad I could help, if it worked please consider marking the answer as correct to help other's find this solution.